# DockPanel does not constrain height

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer, dockpanel

I am trying to limit the height of a DockPanel (well the content acually) to the remaining UserControl Height with a ScrollViewer in it to scroll if its too big.

I have a window wich uses a ContentController to hold the different UserControls

```
<Window>
<Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!--  0 Menu -->
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <!--  1 Header -->
        <RowDefinition Height="65"/>
        <!--  2 Content -->
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <!--  3 Space -->
        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
        <!--  4 Status line -->
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <!--  5 Space -->
        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
<!--...-->
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=MainWindowContent}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"/>
<!--...-->
</Grid>
</Window>
```

The UserControl wich I having trouble with is just a search for users and the output of the results. It does look like this:

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="12"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <!-- input fields -->

                    <DockPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="8" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" LastChildFill="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="{StaticResource PrimaryCorporateBrush}">
                        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HeadlineOutputLabel}" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>


                        <Separator Opacity="0" Height="10" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
                        <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding Path=HasResult, Converter={StaticResource Bool2RevertedVisibility}}" Margin="10" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
                        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="{Binding Path=HasResult, Converter={StaticResource Bool2Visibility}}">
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Members}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Border Tag="{Binding}">
                                            <!-- Result Element -->
                                        </Border>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1">
            <!-- info display -->
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I intent to limit the Results ScrollViewer height to the remaining visible space of the window, and if the results exceed it to display a scrollbar. But right now the DockPanel keeps extending the ScrollViewer and nested ItemsControl height till all elements are placed but does NOT show the ScrollBar.
I am a bit lost here why it does that, shouldn't the DockPanel limit the Height to the visible space? tried it with putting buttons instead of ItemsControl, nothing no ScrollBar.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

Further up in the Grid structure there was a row set to "auto" instead of "*" and ScrollViewer seems to only function properly with latter.